# EMI suppression from vibration disc motors

Tags: power-supply, noise, emi-filtering, vibration-motor

In my application I'm using 9V (6xAA batteries) to power three vibration disc motors in series (Solarbotics P/N:VPM2,) some LEDs (not shown) and then to a non-isolated DC-DC buck converter. The buck converter steps down to 5V for several other devices such as a microcontroller operating at 16MHz, logic chips, and other circuitry (also not shown).)

Because the motor gives off EMI, my concern is that this would creep into my buck converter and possibly to the microcontroller and cause problems. I am not sure if my solutions will help.

The first circuit is just showing the basic circuit with only C1, C2, C3 as decoupling capacitors to suppress any noise from the motor leads. The motors will simply be on for few seconds/off for few seconds.

My idea/s were either circuit 2 or circuit 3 (zoomed into the top portion of first circuit) to help combat EMI using differential chokes and common mode chokes.

In the 2nd circuit, I'm thinking that the chokes are close to motor circuitry to suppress noise before it heads down the wires near DC-DC converter.

In the 3rd circuit, the chokes are located closer to the DC-DC converter. I'm hoping this will help with suppressing RF noise around the switching frequency of 910kHz of the buck converter but I am not sure if this is even an issue and also if I should be worried about noise at a frequency near the clock frequency of the microcontroller (16MHz.) I will also be using bypass capacitors near all chips.

Any advice on this would be helpful or if there are better ways to go about solving this issue.

**Circuit 1 (Only capacitors)**

[image: Circuit 1]

**Circuit 2 (Option 1 for addition of chokes)**

[image: Circuit 2]

**Circuit 3 (Option 2 for addition of chokes)**

[image: Circuit 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a one-off prototype, you're probably over-thinking it.

A 1 nf as close as possible to each motor, and one zener diode to protect the MOSFET. A cheap nasty buck converter will generate a ton of noise too.

A bigger concern might be the voltage drop when you start the motors, especially when the battery is nearly dead. I've had this before, the voltage drop was so severe that the best solution was a diode and capacitor arrangement that prevented the motors from discharging the microcontroller capacitors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd0QoJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also consider a slower motor start using PWM.

You'll need to do more to pass formal testing for EMC, starting with the buck converter and Arduino.

Comment: I usually do overthink the circuitry just because I try to cover all my bases. At the time I bought those buck converters I didn’t know there was a newer better version available. So I still want to use them. This project doesn’t really have to pass any formal EMC regulations, at least not that I’m aware of since it’s mainly hobby. Do you think the chokes are overkill?

Comment: No harm in adding a choke, but neither of your two options. Put it in series with both wires supplying the motors, only, keep the MOSFET ground common with the circuit. I'd still say your biggest risk is the motor current causing a voltage dip that resets the micro, I had this once. Check that carefully, even when the battery is nearly empty... Mitigate with a diode, then enough capacitors to power the micro for 0.25 s, then the buck converter.

Comment: Sorry to ask again but so just to clarify. Would I want to keep L1  as a common mode and get rid of L2 and L3 chokes or just keep  the two L2 and L3 and get rid of L1? I’m going to definitely consider that issue with motors and test that out. I’ll add some bypass caps to battery as you mentioned. When you say mitigate with diode, in what way? I’m possibly going to go an change out the buck for a much better one.

Comment: I've drawn the diode arrangement. And I take back the common mode choke idea - it won't help at all. Chokes are for a different EMC scenario (where the noisy device is connected to both to the mains supply and to other wires like the monitor or the mouse, then it helps to prevent CM noise). What you are concerned about is Differential Mode noise. Common mode is almost impossible, unless there's a lot of capactive coupling from the motors to some large metal object.  If you see a lot of high frequency noise on the 9 V line you could try an inductor too.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I’ll take this all into consideration. I might actually modify my original idea to remedy most of these problems. But I appreciate the details you mentioned.